# How does Amiibo Level Up work?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4, amiibo

What actually happens when an Amiibo levels up and what causes it to level up?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this thread I was unable to find it previously.

Comment: After further reading I still found nothing there on the topic of what specifically triggers the level up of the Amiibo

Comment: In the question, it says "The more the amiibo is played, the more it levels up".

Comment: I understand that is the general way but what is the specific thing that triggers each individual event.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Super Smash Bros wikia](http://www.ssbwiki.com/amiibo#In_Super_Smash_Bros._4):

> Amiibo can be used as a specialized computer player, with the tag "FP" (*Figure Player*) above them.
>   **Figure Players** start at level 1 like regular CPU players, but as they fight more often, they can continue to level up, to a cap of 50.
>   As they gain levels, amiibo can potentially "learn" techniques from other characters: if a player frequently uses long-ranged, camping techniques, then the amiibo will also begin to emulate this behavior. This learning continues even after the 50 level cap is reached.
>
> In addition, an amiibo can gain improved fighting statistics, such as improved damage, knockback, and reaction times, the higher its level is. Finally, higher-leveled Amiibo can adapt to individual matches faster than lower-leveled Amiibo.